# How to set a particular state of a parent component from child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React. I'm trying to do simple validation of a form elements. I'm stuck at validating input data and setting the 'name_error' state as the error msg inside `<p>` tag. Leaving my code below

```
// App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ValidateName from './component/validation';
import Modal from './modal';

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    show: false,
    name: "",
    name_error: ""
  }

  handleChanges = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({[name] : value})
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this)
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='Main'>
          {/* < Main /> */}
          <button id='add' onClick={()=>{this.setState({show: true})}}>Add</button>
        </div>
        {this.state.show && 
          <Modal>
            <form>
              <div className='modalContainer'>
                <b className='title'>Register</b>
                <button id='xmark' onClick={()=>{this.setState({show: false})}} >&times;</button>
                <label for='name' >Name</label><br />
                <input type="text" id='name' placeholder='Enter your name here' name="name" onChange={this.handleChanges}/><br />
                < ValidateName content={this.state.name} />
                <button type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
                <button>Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </Modal>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;

// Modal.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Modal extends Component {
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Modal;

//validation.js
class ValidateName extends Component {
    err1 ='Please enter any name';
    err2 = 'Use only letters in this field';
    render() { 
        const ren = this.props.content.length === 0 ? (<p>{this.err1}</p> ) : 
                (this.props.content.match(/[a-zA-Z]+$/) ? '' : <p>{this.err2}</p>)
        return ren;
    }
}
```

Please suggest an idea to set `name_error` as '*Please enter any name*' or '*Use only letters in this field*' when user enters wrong input

Answer (score 0):

State should be like this,

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
    show: false,
    name: "",
    name_error: ""
  }
}
```

And Also the update state using callback. It would be helpful,

```
this.setState({[name] : value},() =>{console.log(this.state)})
```